# JS fetch() | How to hide console error on 404?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http-status-code-404, fetch-api

I'm using javascripts `fetch()` method to check if a file on the server exists, if not i want to fallback to fetching another default file. In [this article](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/) I allready learned that JS does not throw an error if the request results in an 404 Error, but sets `response.ok` to false.

So my code looks like this now:

```js
let resp;

resp = await fetch("url1"); //check for custom file at url1
if (!resp.ok) { resp = await fetch("url2"); } //if not found use default file at url2
```

It work's as expected, but: if the first request returns a 404-Status Code the console allways shows an error for the 404 Response. **I dont want to see the Error in the console** because it looks like an application error, but just means that the default file was loaded... Any Ideas how to fix this?
I'm using Chrome and it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot - error in Chrome's console]

Comment: You can't disable this error message. _"I dont want to see the Error in the console"_: Close the console.

Comment: You can use a browser extension.

Comment: You could fetch some server side code, that checks for file existence for you. I think that would be called a Proxy

Comment: @jabaa Using a browser extension would work for me...
But I just have a bad feeling to sell software, which spits out error messages at every startup, although everything is actually fine...

Comment: @yunzen A server side solution will require a bit of extra work, but seems to be a nice workaround. Thanks for this idea!